# How to add a password to my samsung printer

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, password-protection

I bought a samsung printer (C410) and already downloaded it on a couple of laptops using the easy printer manager, I would like to password protect that printer so whenever someone wants to print from these devices they have to supply a password or be denied access, I got my printers ip address and logged in, I don't know what to do next

Comment: This is normally done with third-party software and.or a printer server.

Comment: well, great how

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/212461/how_to_password_protect_a_printer.html Suggest you limit it by account and avoid third-party software when possible

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, doing this will need all network settings including the SyncThru username and password. If you had manually configured IP info or were connected to a wireless network, you will need to enter those settings. You could check the link below about how to setup Wifi Direct.
http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=432390&modelname=&modelcode=SL-C480FW%2FXAA&session_id=&from_osc=